# Is there a way in Rails to forbid any actions (insert/destroy) on all activerecord objects

Tags: activerecord

I want to have a setup where nothing is allowed to alter database state. Then I want to be able incrementally white-list allowed operations.

Comment: for a resource, you can add `except: [:new, :create, :update, :destroy]` for respective resource in `config/routes.rb` file

Answer (score 1):

Extend activerecord base.

```
class MyAuthoritarianRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  # crazy logic here
  def destroy
    if user.wont_submit_to_bondage_and_discipline?
      # silently fail
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

class PropertyOfTheState < MyAuthoritarianRecord

end
```